# Use python to open a new xterm window to run another script and then trying to kill using Ctrl+C

Tags: python, linux, xterm

I have been working on a python script, *a.py*, to open a new xterm terminal window and run another script, *b*. The purpose of using *a.py* to launch *b* is because *a.py* will setup some inputs to *b*. After *a.py* runs *b* in the new window, I want to keep the new window around to view the results.

Some quick info on *b*

- *b* launches other processes
- When *b* is running and I do a Ctrl+C, it catches the interrupt signal and kills its processes as part of its cleanup
- *b* is managed by someone else so I cannot change it easily.

I want to replicate how *b* handles the interrupt (Ctrl+C) when I run it from *a.py*.

What I have so far looks something like this

```
...
command = 'xterm -e bash -c "b; exec bash"'
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, shell=True) 
...
```

Launching *b* in the new window seems to work but when I try to do a Ctrl+C, the new xterm window closes before *b* can do its cleanup.

I have tried to change the command to below to keep the window open, but I get a SIGHUP exception while *b* is doing its cleanup (and as a result, *b* does not finish its cleanup).

```
command = 'xterm -hold -e bash -c "b; exec bash"'
```

Does anyone know how I can keep the new window open from *a.py* so *b* can finish its cleanup?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You're assuming that sending sigint to xterm will be like asking xterm to sigint the process. It will instead just close the `xterm`, resulting in the sighup. You can instead run `xterm` in a different session so it won't be affected by Ctrl-C, and then have your Python process intercept the signal, find the pid of `b`, and send it a new sigint yourself.

Comment: @thatotherguy my python process currently ends right after it launches the command to leave the original terminal usable. Would I have to change my python process to wait in a loop for either `b` to finish or a Ctrl-C before exiting?